# Sum all rows when at least one row meets the criteria

Tags: excel

I have a database as follows:

[image]

I am having issues trying to sum all the quantities by groups when the “Included” flag is Y for at least one of the groups; that is: if there’s a Y on at least one row from group 3 , sum all the rows from group 3, regardless if the rest are not included.

The output should be like this:

[image: Expected output]

Thanks!

Comment: Please take some time to learn about Stack Overflow by taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), reading about how to ask a question, how to answer a question, how to accept answers, etc. You will get much more out of this site, and it will serve you well if you serve it well.

Comment: I'm not sure why your question was down voted, and it's kind of rude for people to do that without telling you what to fix. It might appear that you have done no work, but I can see that you have, so no problem there. It would help to have your sample data as text instead of images, but I don't think that's a reason to down vote. Having text allows people to copy it more easily and create a test environment. Some people like to see an actual question, but I feel like your "question" is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use an array function to solve this one. To enter and array function, type a function as you normally would then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead just Enter. (Apple Keyboards differ, but I don't have Apple.)

I'll explain how I put the function together, then bring it all together in the end.

First, I wanted an array of group numbers that have at least one "Y" in the Included column. That array is created by `IF(B2:B14="Y",A2:A14,0)`. The result would be `{0,0,0,0,0,0,3,...etc}` in the sample case.

Next, I flag every group row that has an entry in the list of group numbers using the `MATCH(A2:A14,IF(B2:B14="Y",A2:A14,0),0)` function.

Since that uses an exact match, it will create an error when there is no match. `ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A14,IF(B2:B14="Y",A2:A14,0),0))` gives me a true when there is not a match and a false when there is, so I negate it. `NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A14,IF(B2:B14="Y",A2:A14,0),0)))`

Another IF converts this to a 1 or a 0.
`IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A14,IF(B2:B14="Y",A2:A14,0),0))),1,0)`

Finally, I bring it together with the Quantity using a SUMPRODUCT:
`=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C14,IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A14,IF(B2:B14="Y",A2:A14,0),0))),1,0))`

Again, remember to Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make this work.

Tested in Excel 2013 and it works fine.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I needed a way to create the {0,1} array but couldn't come up with the solution. However, is there any way to create it without using ISERROR? I need to apply it to a large database and may affect calculation performance. PD: Sorry if i have approached this question rather wrongly, where did I make a mistake? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to avoid using ISERROR.